# SQL Insert into … ( SELECT *, SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM … )

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure that should do 2 inserts in one

First step I want to create a new entry per insert into.

Second step I will catch the created Id from this entry

Third step I want to copie multiple entries per select from one table and insert those to the same table with the Id

```
Create PROCEDURE dbo.Rolle_Copie
    @Id as int,
    @newId as int = 0,
    @Name AS nvarchar(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Rollen (RolleName) 
    VALUES (@Name)

    @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO Berechtigung_Rolle (RefRolleId,RefBerechtigungId)
        SELECT   
           RefBerechtigungId, @newId 
        FROM     
           Berechtigung_Rolle 
        WHERE    
           RefRolleId = @Id

    RETURN
```

but I get an error

> *Wrong syntax next to @newId*

Could somebody please enlight me what's wrong?

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: When you have a calm moment to learn something new, have a look at `OUTPUT`.  You can use an `OUTPUT` clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. `Id` values.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` and provides access to both before and after values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

don't forget to use `SET`

```
SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Is it possible to just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` within the INSERT query? Like so `INSERT INTO Berechtigung_Rolle  (RefRolleId,RefBerechtigungId)
                            SELECT   RefBerechtigungId, SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
                            FROM     Berechtigung_Rolle 
                            WHERE    RefRolleId = @Id`?

Comment: @JoeFletch yes, i was just pointing out on how you can set it to a variable using `SET`

Comment: Seems reasonable! Thanks! And sorry, I was not criticizing the answer, I was just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: @JoeFletch no no no! Don't think it negatively. Wait i'll rephrase the answer `:D`

Comment: mhh it looks like SCOPE_IDENTITY() doesn't contains the value i need o.O because i get a FOREIGN KEY-Restriction that means i got a wrong value for my Id so what should i us instate of SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: try, `SET @newId = IDENT_CURRENT('Rollen')`  by the way, here's the source: [SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: do you now a easy way to check the Values in the procedure?

Comment: you have different column order Berechtigung_Rolle (RefRolleId,RefBerechtigungId) and in select RefBerechtigungId, @newId